# How to create a dropdown list in a Shiny table using datatable when editing the table?

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I used RStudio to read in a csv file and used Shiny to build an app as an interactive table, the cell I selected right now as shown in the picture is pre-filled.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DUv5.png)

I want to change the value given pre-defined options in a dropdown list, such as, "Keep Dataset", "Pass", etc., I searched hundreds of materials and I literally ran out of my bullets...... PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Do you want the same dropdown list in all the cells of the column?

Comment: Yes, that would work, can you elaborate this? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593539/edit-datatable-in-shiny-with-dropdown-selection-for-factor-variables, but Stephane Laurent gave a fantastic answer here, whereas the other question does not have an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do that with the JavaScript library [CellEdit](https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit). Download the file [dataTables.cellEdit.js](https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit/tree/master/js).

By default, the interface is not very stylish. To style it, copy the CSS code below and put it in a file **dataTables.cellEdit.css**, in the same folder as **dataTables.cellEdit.js**.

```css
.my-input-class {
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.my-confirm-class {
  padding: 3px 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.my-cancel-class {
  padding: 3px 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #a94442;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Now, here is the R code. Don't forget to change the `path` variable.

```r
library(DT)

dat <- data.frame(
  Action = c("Keep data", "Keep data", "Keep data"),
  X = c(1, 2, 3),
  Y = c("a", "b", "c")
)

callback = JS(
  "function onUpdate(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue){}",
  "table.MakeCellsEditable({",
  "  onUpdate: onUpdate,",
  "  inputCss: 'my-input-class',",
  "  confirmationButton: {",
  "    confirmCss: 'my-confirm-class',",
  "    cancelCss: 'my-cancel-class'",
  "  },",
  "  inputTypes: [",
  "    {",
  "      column: 0,",
  "      type: 'list',",
  "      options: [",
  "        {value: 'Keep data', display: 'Keep data'},",
  "        {value: 'Pass',      display: 'Pass'},",
  "        {value: 'Delete',    display: 'Delete'}",
  "      ]",
  "    }",
  "  ]",
  "});")

## the datatable
dtable <- datatable(
  dat, callback = callback, rownames = FALSE, 
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")
    )
  )
)
path <- "~/Work/R/DT" # folder containing the files dataTables.cellEdit.js
                      # and dataTables.cellEdit.css
dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "CellEdit", "1.0.19", path, 
  script = "dataTables.cellEdit.js", stylesheet = "dataTables.cellEdit.css")
dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))
dtable
```

See it in action:

[image]

See the possible options on the [CellEdit repo](https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit). In particular you can disable the editing for certain columns, and you can get rid of the Confirm/Cancel buttons if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible not to refer an outside file "CellEdit.js"? Is it possible to use a callback within DT, downloading an extra file would be more complex for the third one if he/she wants to use this app, but I understand if we have to do so......