# Package replacement of rhanfsontable or DT in R Shiny to create editable table with dropdown list

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt, rhandsontable

I am trying to create a shiny app to modify a input csv file table and modify just one column value, with a given dropdown list.

I tried DT, which does not essentially provide a dropdown list to update the table, but DT reacts and renders really fast. and I tried rhandsontable, which performs EXTREMELY slow when it is rendering the updated table, I was stuck.

I read about some other package, like DTedit, but it seems to not be included in CRAN and I got difficulties when I tried to download it from github.

May I ask is there any thoughts regarding my needs? Thank you in advance, sincerely.

Comment: Do you want only one editable cell?

Comment: Hi, I only want one column to be editable, one cell at each time to be edited given a dropdownlist.

Comment: Ok. Then see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60845695/1100107

Comment: Thank you Stephane, actually, that is one of my other posts...... I am still wondering is there any ways to achieve that without an external file......