# Reexecute js callbacks in shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I wanted to extend solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593539/edit-datatable-in-shiny-with-dropdown-selection-for-factor-variables). This code renders dropdowns with options for last column of the dataset and it works perfectly for static dataset.

When I'm adding new row and re-rendering the table dropdown disappears
though I have callback variable in `renderDT` function. Is it possible to have the dropdown for every rendering of the table? What could cause the issue?

Here's my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

callback <- c(
    "var id = $(table.table().node()).closest('.datatables').attr('id');",
    "$.contextMenu({",
    "  selector: '#' + id + ' td.factor input[type=text]',", 
    "  trigger: 'hover',",
    "  build: function($trigger, e){",
    "    var colindex = table.cell($trigger.parent()[0]).index().column;",
    "    var coldata = table.column(colindex).data().unique();",
    "    var options = coldata.reduce(function(result, item, index, array){",
    "      result[index] = item;",
    "      return result;",
    "    }, {});",
    "    return {",
    "      autoHide: true,",
    "      items: {",
    "        dropdown: {",
    "          name: 'Edit',", 
    "          type: 'select',", 
    "          options: options,",
    "          selected: 0", 
    "        }",
    "      },",
    "      events: {",
    "        show: function(opts){",
    "          opts.$trigger.off('blur');",
    "        },",
    "        hide: function(opts){",
    "          var $this = this;",
    "          var data = $.contextMenu.getInputValues(opts, $this.data());",
    "          var $input = opts.$trigger;",
    "          $input.val(options[data.dropdown]);",
    "          $input.trigger('change');",
    "        }",
    "      }",
    "    };",
    "  }",
    "});" 
)
ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$link(
            rel = "stylesheet", 
            href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.8.0/jquery.contextMenu.min.css"
        ),
        tags$script(
            src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.8.0/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"
        )
    ),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(actionButton("add", "Add row"),),
        mainPanel(DTOutput("dtable"))
    )
    
)

server <- function(input, output){
    output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
        iris2 <<- iris
        datatable(
            iris2, editable = "cell", callback = JS(callback), 
            options = list(
                columnDefs = list(
                    list(
                        targets = 5, className = "factor"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    }, server = FALSE) 
    
    observeEvent(input$add, {
        new.row <- t(rep(NA, ncol(iris2)))
        colnames(new.row) <- colnames(iris2)
        new.row <- data.table(new.row)
        iris2 <<- rbind(new.row,iris2)
        output$dtable <- renderDT({
            datatable(
                iris2, editable = "cell", 
                callback = JS(callback),
                options = list(
                    columnDefs = list(
                        list(
                            targets = 5 , className = "factor"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        }, server = TRUE)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know you can use the datatableProxy? It can be used to manipulate an existing datatable instance. This seems to be working

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

callback <- c(
    "var id = $(table.table().node()).closest('.datatables').attr('id');",
    "$.contextMenu({",
    "  selector: '#' + id + ' td.factor input[type=text]',", 
    "  trigger: 'hover',",
    "  build: function($trigger, e){",
    "    var colindex = table.cell($trigger.parent()[0]).index().column;",
    "    var coldata = table.column(colindex).data().unique();",
    "    var options = coldata.reduce(function(result, item, index, array){",
    "      result[index] = item;",
    "      return result;",
    "    }, {});",
    "    return {",
    "      autoHide: true,",
    "      items: {",
    "        dropdown: {",
    "          name: 'Edit',", 
    "          type: 'select',", 
    "          options: options,",
    "          selected: 0", 
    "        }",
    "      },",
    "      events: {",
    "        show: function(opts){",
    "          opts.$trigger.off('blur');",
    "        },",
    "        hide: function(opts){",
    "          var $this = this;",
    "          var data = $.contextMenu.getInputValues(opts, $this.data());",
    "          var $input = opts.$trigger;",
    "          $input.val(options[data.dropdown]);",
    "          $input.trigger('change');",
    "        }",
    "      }",
    "    };",
    "  }",
    "});" 
)
ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$link(
            rel = "stylesheet", 
            href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.8.0/jquery.contextMenu.min.css"
        ),
        tags$script(
            src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.8.0/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"
        )
    ),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(actionButton("add", "Add row"),),
        mainPanel(DTOutput("dtable"))
    )
    
)

server <- function(input, output){
    output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
        iris2 <<- iris
        datatable(
            iris2, editable = "cell", callback = JS(callback), 
            options = list(
                columnDefs = list(
                    list(
                        targets = 5, className = "factor"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    }, server = FALSE) 
    
    proxy = dataTableProxy('dtable')
    
    observeEvent(input$add, {
        new.row <- t(rep(NA, ncol(iris2)))
        colnames(new.row) <- colnames(iris2)
        new.row <- data.table(new.row)
        
        proxy %>% addRow(new.row)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved issue with adding rows. I had a look at the documentation and `reloadData()` with proxy would be very helpful. I need to navigate between different dataframes assigned to `iris2` (with diffenent number of rows and columns, I need to choose the one I want to edit from list) but documentation says  that "The data to be reloaded (i.e. the one you pass to `dataTableAjax()`) must have exactly the same number of columns as the previous data object in the table." Do you have an idea how could I solve this issue?

Comment: do you know the maximum number of columns at front? Then you could add some dummy columns for the dataframes that have less columns