# Edit datatable in shiny with dropdown selection (for DT v0.19)

Tags: jquery, r, shiny, callback, dt

I based the code below on Stephane Laurent's solution to the following question on Stack Overflow:

[Edit datatable in Shiny with dropdown selection for factor variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593539/edit-datatable-in-shiny-with-dropdown-selection-for-factor-variables)

I added in code to use editData to update the table and to be able to save/export the updates.

The following works with DT v0.18 but with DT v0.19 I found the id_cell_edit seems to not be triggering.  I am unsure if it has to do with the callback or possibly jquery.contextMenu given DT v0.19 upgraded to jquery 3.0. Would appreciate any insight people may have on how to work through this.

Here is a description of the behavior I observe when using v0.18. When I select the usage column and update the value for the first row from the default “sel” to “id” the value changes in the DT table.  I also see it updates the view of the tibble and thus the data in the download csv file is also updated.  If I progress to the Next page to see the 11th item, and then return back to the first page, I can see the record I updated still says “id”.

Here is a description of the behavior I observe when using v0.19. When I select the usage column and update the value for the first row from the default “sel” to “id” the value changes in the DT table.  It does not update the view of the tibble and thus the data in the download csv file does not get updated.  If I progress to the Next page to see the 11th item, and then return back to the first page, the update I had made gets cleared.

Note that I also ran reactive graphs using reactlog. I followed the same steps to update the usage column of the first row to "id". The first difference I note is that reactiveValues###$dt at Step 5 gives me a list of 7 when I use version v0.18 and a list of 8 when I use version v0.19. At Step 16, for v0.18 input$dt_cell_edit invalidates, then Data invalidates and output$table invalidates. At Step 16 when using v0.19, however, output$dt invalidates then output$table invalidates. In other words, when using v0.19 input$dt_cell_edit and Data are not invalidating.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

cars_df <- mtcars
cars_meta <- dplyr::tibble(variables = names(cars_df), data_class = sapply(cars_df, class), usage = "sel")
cars_meta$data_class <- factor(cars_meta$data_class,  c("numeric", "character", "factor", "logical"))
cars_meta$usage <- factor(cars_meta$usage,  c("id", "meta", "demo", "sel", "text"))


callback <- c(
    "var id = $(table.table().node()).closest('.datatables').attr('id');",
    "$.contextMenu({",
    "  selector: '#' + id + ' td.factor input[type=text]',",
    "  trigger: 'hover',",
    "  build: function($trigger, e){",
    "    var levels = $trigger.parent().data('levels');",
    "    if(levels === undefined){",
    "      var colindex = table.cell($trigger.parent()[0]).index().column;",
    "      levels = table.column(colindex).data().unique();",
    "    }",
    "    var options = levels.reduce(function(result, item, index, array){",
    "      result[index] = item;",
    "      return result;",
    "    }, {});",
    "    return {",
    "      autoHide: true,",
    "      items: {",
    "        dropdown: {",
    "          name: 'Edit',",
    "          type: 'select',",
    "          options: options,",
    "          selected: 0",
    "        }",
    "      },",
    "      events: {",
    "        show: function(opts){",
    "          opts.$trigger.off('blur');",
    "        },",
    "        hide: function(opts){",
    "          var $this = this;",
    "          var data = $.contextMenu.getInputValues(opts, $this.data());",
    "          var $input = opts.$trigger;",
    "          $input.val(options[data.dropdown]);",
    "          $input.trigger('change');",
    "        }",
    "      }",
    "    };",
    "  }",
    "});"
)

createdCell <- function(levels){
    if(missing(levels)){
        return("function(td, cellData, rowData, rowIndex, colIndex){}")
    }
    quotedLevels <- toString(sprintf("\"%s\"", levels))
    c(
        "function(td, cellData, rowData, rowIndex, colIndex){",
        sprintf("  $(td).attr('data-levels', '[%s]');", quotedLevels),
        "}"
    )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$link(
            rel = "stylesheet",
            href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.8.0/jquery.contextMenu.min.css"
        ),
        tags$script(
            src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.8.0/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"
        )
    ),
    DTOutput("dt"),
    br(),
    verbatimTextOutput("table"),
    br(),
    downloadButton('download',"Download the data")
    
)

server <- function(input, output){
    
    dat <- cars_meta
    
    value <- reactiveValues()
    value$dt<-
        datatable(
            dat, editable = "cell", callback = JS(callback),
            options = list(
                columnDefs = list(
                    list(
                        targets = 2,
                        className = "factor",
                        createdCell = JS(createdCell(c(levels(cars_meta$data_class), "another level")))
                    ),
                    list(
                        targets = 3,
                        className = "factor",
                        createdCell = JS(createdCell(c(levels(cars_meta$usage), "another level")))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    
    output[["dt"]] <- renderDT({
        value$dt
        
    }, 
    server = TRUE)
    
    Data <- reactive({
        info <- input[["dt_cell_edit"]]
        if(!is.null(info)){
            info <- unique(info)
            info$value[info$value==""] <- NA
            dat <-  editData(dat, info, proxy = "dt")
        }
        dat
    })
    
    
    #output table to be able to confirm the table updates
    output[["table"]] <- renderPrint({Data()})  
    
    output$download <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function(){"Data.csv"}, 
        content = function(fname){
            write.csv(Data(), fname)
        }
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Below I've leveraged [ismirsehregal's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69344974/dt-dynamically-change-column-values-based-on-selectinput-from-another-column-in/69389649#69389649) into my use case. I also added in the renderPrint/verbatimTextOutput to illustrate what I am trying to do with the underlying data. I'd like to be able to capture the values not the input containers. Essentially with the code I am trying to give the User a dataset, allow them to change some values but restrict the choices with dropdowns, and then use the updated dataset for further processing. At this point in the solution I don't know how to get to the updated dataset so that I can use it, for example, to export to a csv file.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)


cars_df <- mtcars
selectInputIDa <- paste0("sela", 1:length(cars_df))
selectInputIDb <- paste0("selb", 1:length(cars_df))

initMeta <- dplyr::tibble(
    variables = names(cars_df), 
    data_class = sapply(selectInputIDa, function(x){as.character(selectInput(inputId = x, label = "", choices = c("character","numeric", "factor", "logical"), selected = sapply(cars_df, class)))}),
    usage = sapply(selectInputIDb, function(x){as.character(selectInput(inputId = x, label = "", choices = c("id", "meta", "demo", "sel", "text"), selected = "sel"))})
)



ui <- fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = 'my_table'),
    br(),
    verbatimTextOutput("table")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    
    displayTbl <- reactive({
        dplyr::tibble(
            variables = names(cars_df), 
            data_class = sapply(selectInputIDa, function(x){as.character(selectInput(inputId = x, label = "", choices = c("numeric", "character", "factor", "logical"), selected = input[[x]]))}),
            usage = sapply(selectInputIDb, function(x){as.character(selectInput(inputId = x, label = "", choices = c("id", "meta", "demo", "sel", "text"), selected = input[[x]]))})
        )
    })
    
    

    
    output$my_table = DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(
            initMeta, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', rownames = FALSE,
            options = list(paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE, scrollx = TRUE, dom = "t",
                           preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                           drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
            )
        )
    }, server = TRUE)
    
    my_table_proxy <- dataTableProxy(outputId = "my_table", session = session)
    
    observeEvent({sapply(selectInputIDa, function(x){input[[x]]})}, {
        replaceData(proxy = my_table_proxy, data = displayTbl(), rownames = FALSE) # must repeat rownames = FALSE see ?replaceData and ?dataTableAjax
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    
    observeEvent({sapply(selectInputIDb, function(x){input[[x]]})}, {
        replaceData(proxy = my_table_proxy, data = displayTbl(), rownames = FALSE) # must repeat rownames = FALSE see ?replaceData and ?dataTableAjax
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    
    
    
    output$table <- renderPrint({displayTbl()})  
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You wrote that this wasn't working. However, is there any chance that the problem is a specific functionality isn't working? I have DT .19, and I visited the origin of the code using the URL you provided. I see the table; I can edit and highlight rows. Downloading works. What am I missing?

Comment: Kat, thank you for taking the time to look at this.  I have added more context regarding what behavior I see and subsequently ran some comparisons using reactlog which I've also included.

Comment: Have you thought about skipping the JS? [Check out these examples](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/).

Comment: And this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69344974/dt-dynamically-change-column-values-based-on-selectinput-from-another-column-in/69389649#69389649).

Comment: @ismirsehregal - thank you for highlighting this approach to creating the drop downs. I was able to apply it to my example. Where I am now stuck, though, is how to use the updated datatable elsewhere in my app. In my original example I exported the updated table, for instance. If I use renderPrint/verbatimTextOutput on displayTbl() in this example, I just see the container, not the values. Any further advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing your current code. Can you please update your question with it?

Comment: @ismirsehregal, I've added in the example. Thank you.

Comment: @stomper Please check if my answer meets your expectations.

Comment: @ismirsehregal  This is exactly what I was looking to do. Clearly I didn't have my head wrapped around it enough to work out that last step. It is an elegant solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the `resultTbl` you can just access the `input[x]`'s:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

cars_df <- mtcars
selectInputIDa <- paste0("sela", 1:length(cars_df))
selectInputIDb <- paste0("selb", 1:length(cars_df))

initMeta <- dplyr::tibble(
  variables = names(cars_df), 
  data_class = sapply(selectInputIDa, function(x){as.character(selectInput(inputId = x, label = "", choices = c("character","numeric", "factor", "logical"), selected = sapply(cars_df, class)))}),
  usage = sapply(selectInputIDb, function(x){as.character(selectInput(inputId = x, label = "", choices = c("id", "meta", "demo", "sel", "text"), selected = "sel"))})
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = 'my_table'),
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  displayTbl <- reactive({
    dplyr::tibble(
      variables = names(cars_df), 
      data_class = sapply(selectInputIDa, function(x){as.character(selectInput(inputId = x, label = "", choices = c("numeric", "character", "factor", "logical"), selected = input[[x]]))}),
      usage = sapply(selectInputIDb, function(x){as.character(selectInput(inputId = x, label = "", choices = c("id", "meta", "demo", "sel", "text"), selected = input[[x]]))})
    )
  })
  
  resultTbl <- reactive({
    dplyr::tibble(
      variables = names(cars_df), 
      data_class = sapply(selectInputIDa, function(x){input[[x]]}),
      usage = sapply(selectInputIDb, function(x){input[[x]]})
    )
  })
  
  output$my_table = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(
      initMeta, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', rownames = FALSE,
      options = list(paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE, scrollx = TRUE, dom = "t",
                     preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                     drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
      )
    )
  }, server = TRUE)
  
  my_table_proxy <- dataTableProxy(outputId = "my_table", session = session)
  
  observeEvent({sapply(selectInputIDa, function(x){input[[x]]})}, {
    replaceData(proxy = my_table_proxy, data = displayTbl(), rownames = FALSE) # must repeat rownames = FALSE see ?replaceData and ?dataTableAjax
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  observeEvent({sapply(selectInputIDb, function(x){input[[x]]})}, {
    replaceData(proxy = my_table_proxy, data = displayTbl(), rownames = FALSE) # must repeat rownames = FALSE see ?replaceData and ?dataTableAjax
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  output$table <- renderPrint({resultTbl()})  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

PS: This is based on my earlier answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69344974/dt-dynamically-change-column-values-based-on-selectinput-from-another-column-in/69389649#69389649).

PPS: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75948475/value-not-updated-in-shiny-using-dt-and-drop-down-selection/75950123#75950123) a follow-up post can be found.

Comment: Unfortunately, as of 2024 this does not work anymore. It's a pity, I needed something very similar to this. Can you please update?

Comment: @panman I currently can't test it but [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3979) a related GitHub issue can be found.

Comment: I'm on the road right now, so I can't test this one, but I had a similar issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77908474/r-shiny-dt-cell-drop-down-menus-values-are-not-updated-and-not-collected-anymor) and adding `selectize = FALSE` to the call to `selectInput` solved the problem.