# Problem capturing edited data table output in modularized shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, module, dt

I have a shiny app that utilizes a data table with drop down menus to control the updates of select columns. When I modularize the shiny app, I am no longer able to capture the results of the updated table. The approach I am following for the drop down menus is based on a response I received to an earlier question (@ismirsehregal).

< [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69959720/edit-datatable-in-shiny-with-dropdown-selection-for-dt-v0-19>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69959720/edit-datatable-in-shiny-with-dropdown-selection-for-dt-v0-19%3E)

Below I’ve provided two versions of my app, ***nonmod2_app*** and ***mod2_app***.  The first is without modules and works as desired. The second is a modularized version and I am getting NULL in the output.

When the User runs the app they are presented with a Load Data button which loads the cars data  as **cars_df** and creates a new table I call **cars_meta** with three values. It then creates a list called **cars_object** to which **cars_df** and **cars_meta** are added. This is then made a reactive value, **cars_reactive**.

The User is then presented with a an editable data table **(initTbl)** of the reactive **cars_reactive$cars_meta** for which they can update the values of two fields via drop down menus. When the User is done making updates and selects the Commit button, the results of the selections are saved as **cars_reactive$cars_meta**. I display the updated **cars_reactive$cars_meta** as verbatimTextOutput so one can see how it was updated.

In both examples, I update the first class value from “numeric” to “character” and select Commit. In the ***nonmod2_app*** version the results table holds the original values and reflects the one I updated.

[image: nonmod_output]

In the ***mod2_app*** version, I get NULL for all values of the two selectable fields.

[image: mod1_output]

I suspect it has something to do with namespace, but am at a loss to figure out what is missing.

Here is the ui and server code for the non modularized version.

```
#------- LIBRARIES ---------------------

library(dplyr)
library(tidyselect)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)


# ------  UI  ------------------

shiny_ui <- function() {
    fluidPage(
        actionButton("new_data", "Load Data"),
        br(),
        DT::dataTableOutput("main_table"),
        br(),
        actionButton("commit_meta", "Commit"),
        br(),
        verbatimTextOutput("cars_meta")
    )
}




# -------- SERVER  ---------------

shiny_server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    v <- reactiveValues()
    
    #place holders
    selectInputIDclass <- "class"
    selectInputIDusage <- "usage"
    
    observeEvent(input$new_data, once = TRUE, {

        
        cars_df <- mtcars
        
        #simulate creating meta table
        cars_meta <- dplyr::tibble(variable = names(cars_df), class = sapply(cars_df, class), usage = c("val1", "val2", "val3","val1", "val2", "val3","val1", "val2", "val3","val1", "val2"))
        cars_meta$class <- factor(cars_meta$class,  c("numeric", "character", "factor"))
        cars_meta$usage <- factor(cars_meta$usage,  c("val1", "val2", "val3"))
        
        #simulate creating the cars_object
        cars_object <- list()
        cars_object$cars_df <- cars_df
        cars_object$cars_meta <- cars_meta
        

        #make initTbl
        selectInputIDclass <<- paste0("sel_class", 1:nrow(cars_object$cars_meta))
        selectInputIDusage <<- paste0("sel_usage", 1:nrow(cars_object$cars_meta))
        
        v$initTbl <- dplyr::tibble(
            variable = cars_object$cars_meta$variable,
            class = sapply(selectInputIDclass, function(x){as.character(selectInput(inputId = x, label = "", choices = c("character","numeric", "factor"),
                                                                                    selected = cars_object$cars_meta$class[which(selectInputIDclass == x)]))}),
            usage = sapply(selectInputIDusage, function(x){as.character(selectInput(inputId = x, label = "", choices = c("val1", "val2", "val3"),
                                                                                    selected = cars_object$cars_meta$usage[which(selectInputIDusage == x)]))})
        )

        
        v$cars_reactive <- reactive({
            cars_object
        })
    })
    
    
    displayTbl <- reactive({
        dplyr::tibble(
            variable = v$cars_reactive()$cars_meta$variable,
            class = sapply(selectInputIDclass, function(x){as.character(selectInput(inputId = x, label = "", choices = c("numeric", "character", "factor"), selected = input[[x]]))}),
            usage = sapply(selectInputIDusage, function(x){as.character(selectInput(inputId = x, label = "", choices = c("val1", "val2", "val3"), selected = input[[x]]))})
        )
    })
    
    
    resultTbl <- reactive({
        dplyr::tibble(
            variable = v$cars_reactive()$cars_meta$variable,
            class = sapply(selectInputIDclass, function(x){input[[x]]}),
            usage = sapply(selectInputIDusage, function(x){input[[x]]})
        )
    })
    
    
    output$main_table = DT::renderDataTable({
        req(isTruthy(input$new_data))
        DT::datatable(
            v$initTbl, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', rownames = FALSE,
            options = list(paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE, scrollx = TRUE, dom = "t",
                           preDrawCallback = DT::JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                           drawCallback = DT::JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
            )
        )
    }, server = TRUE)
    
    
    main_table_proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy(outputId = "main_table", session = session)
    
    
    observeEvent({sapply(selectInputIDclass, function(x){input[[x]]})}, {
        replaceData(proxy = main_table_proxy, data = displayTbl(), rownames = FALSE)
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    
    
    observeEvent({sapply(selectInputIDusage, function(x){input[[x]]})}, {
        replaceData(proxy = main_table_proxy, data = displayTbl(), rownames = FALSE)
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    
    
    observeEvent(input$commit_meta, {  
        object = v$cars_reactive()
        table = resultTbl()
        object$cars_meta <- table
        v$cars_reactive <- reactive({object})
    })
    
    
    
    
    output$cars_meta <- renderPrint({
        req (input$commit_meta > 0)
        isolate({v$cars_reactive()$cars_meta})
    })
}



# ------- APP ----------

nonmod2_app <- function(...) {
    app <- shiny::shinyApp(
        ui = shiny_ui,
        server = shiny_server
    )
    
    shiny::runApp(app, ...)
}
```

Here is the code for the modularized version.

```
#------- LIBRARIES ---------------------

library(dplyr)
library(tidyselect)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)



# ------  UI MODULE ------------------

mod_ui <- function(id) {
    fluidPage(
        actionButton(NS(id,"new_data"), "Load Data"),
        br(),
        DT::dataTableOutput(NS(id, 'main_table')),
        br(),
        actionButton(NS(id, "commit_meta"), "Commit"),
        br(),
        verbatimTextOutput(NS(id, "cars_meta"))
    )
}


# -------- SERVER MODULE ---------------

mod_server <- function(id) {
    shiny::moduleServer(id, function(input, output,session){
        
        v <- reactiveValues()
        
        #place holders
        selectInputIDclass <- "class"
        selectInputIDusage <- "usage"
        
        observeEvent(input$new_data, once = TRUE, {
            
            
            cars_df <- mtcars
            
            #simulate creating meta table
            cars_meta <- dplyr::tibble(variable = names(cars_df), class = sapply(cars_df, class), usage = c("val1", "val2", "val3","val1", "val2", "val3","val1", "val2", "val3","val1", "val2"))
            cars_meta$class <- factor(cars_meta$class,  c("numeric", "character", "factor"))
            cars_meta$usage <- factor(cars_meta$usage,  c("val1", "val2", "val3"))
            
            #simulate creating the cars_object
            cars_object <- list()
            cars_object$cars_df <- cars_df
            cars_object$cars_meta <- cars_meta
            
            
            #make initTbl
            selectInputIDclass <<- paste0("sel_class", 1:nrow(cars_object$cars_meta))
            selectInputIDusage <<- paste0("sel_usage", 1:nrow(cars_object$cars_meta))
            
            v$initTbl <- dplyr::tibble(
                variable = cars_object$cars_meta$variable,
                class = sapply(selectInputIDclass, function(x){as.character(selectInput(inputId = x, label = "", choices = c("character","numeric", "factor"),
                                                                                        selected = cars_object$cars_meta$class[which(selectInputIDclass == x)]))}),
                usage = sapply(selectInputIDusage, function(x){as.character(selectInput(inputId = x, label = "", choices = c("val1", "val2", "val3"),
                                                                                        selected = cars_object$cars_meta$usage[which(selectInputIDusage == x)]))})
            )
            
            
            v$cars_reactive <- reactive({
                cars_object
            })
        })
        
        
        displayTbl <- reactive({
            dplyr::tibble(
                variable = v$cars_reactive()$cars_meta$variable,
                class = sapply(selectInputIDclass, function(x){as.character(selectInput(inputId = x, label = "", choices = c("numeric", "character", "factor"), selected = input[[x]]))}),
                usage = sapply(selectInputIDusage, function(x){as.character(selectInput(inputId = x, label = "", choices = c("val1", "val2", "val3"), selected = input[[x]]))})
            )
        })
        
        
        resultTbl <- reactive({
            dplyr::tibble(
                variable = v$cars_reactive()$cars_meta$variable,
                class = sapply(selectInputIDclass, function(x){input[[x]]}),
                usage = sapply(selectInputIDusage, function(x){input[[x]]})
            )
        })
        
        
        output$main_table = DT::renderDataTable({
            req(isTruthy(input$new_data))
            DT::datatable(
                v$initTbl, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', rownames = FALSE,
                options = list(paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE, scrollx = TRUE, dom = "t",
                               preDrawCallback = DT::JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                               drawCallback = DT::JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
                )
            )
        }, server = TRUE)
        
        
        main_table_proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy(outputId = "main_table", session = session)
        
        
        observeEvent({sapply(selectInputIDclass, function(x){input[[x]]})}, {
            replaceData(proxy = main_table_proxy, data = displayTbl(), rownames = FALSE)
        }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
        
        
        observeEvent({sapply(selectInputIDusage, function(x){input[[x]]})}, {
            replaceData(proxy = main_table_proxy, data = displayTbl(), rownames = FALSE)
        }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
        
        
        observeEvent(input$commit_meta, {  
            object = v$cars_reactive()
            table = resultTbl()
            object$cars_meta <- table
            v$cars_reactive <- reactive({object})
        })
        
        
        
        
        output$cars_meta <- renderPrint({
            req (input$commit_meta > 0)
            isolate({v$cars_reactive()$cars_meta})
        })
    })
}



# ------- UI SERVER APP ----------

shiny_ui <- function() {
    
    fluidPage(
        mod_ui("data")
    )
    
}


shiny_server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    sv <- mod_server("data")
    
}



mod2_app <- function(...) {
    app <- shiny::shinyApp(
        ui = shiny_ui,
        server = shiny_server
    )
    
    shiny::runApp(app, ...)
}
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have a namespace issue as you have `selectInput`s inside `make_initTbl` function which is called within `create_data` function.

Comment: @YBS Thank you for your insight. I've reposted the code to remove the individual functions create_data and make_initTbl as I've embedded directly into the server side code. I do see the likely namespace problem is with the selectInput() usage in the initTbl and displayTbl and possibly input[[x]] in resultTbl. Am just not sure how to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your new `mod_server`, it works for me.

```
  ns <- session$ns
  v$initTbl <- dplyr::tibble(
    variable = cars_object$cars_meta$variable,
    class = sapply(selectInputIDclass, function(x){as.character(selectInput(inputId = ns(x), label = "", choices = c("character","numeric", "factor"),
                                                                            selected = cars_object$cars_meta$class[which(selectInputIDclass == x)]))}),
    usage = sapply(selectInputIDusage, function(x){as.character(selectInput(inputId = ns(x), label = "", choices = c("val1", "val2", "val3"),
                                                                            selected = cars_object$cars_meta$usage[which(selectInputIDusage == x)]))})
  )
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help me with this!